# PostgreSQL Crosstab with count Query or any other way

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab

I am trying to figure out the `crosstab` function in **postgre SQL** but I have have problem with it. I read several questions and answers but, I can’t transform your answers in my need for some reason.
I have a table that look like below:

```
start1  finish1 year1
1          1    2015
1          2    2013
1          1    2011
1          3    2011
2          2    2014
2          2    2011
2          1    2012
2          3    2015
3          1    2010


create table  test (
start1 int, finish1 int, year1 int);

insert into test values 
(1,1,2015),(1,2,2013),
(1,1,2011),(1,3,2011),
(2,2,2014),(2,2,2011),
(2,1,2012),(2,3,2015),
(3,1,2010);
```

And, I want result like below:

```
      finish        
  start :   1 : 2 : 3
    1   :   2 : 1 : 1
    2   :   1 : 2 : 1
    3   :   1 : 0 : 0
```

To have all the start and finish points and count how many they finish at the same point.

I written query like below to achieve above output:

```
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
      'SELECT polygon_id, count(dest_polygon_id)
       FROM   test
       ORDER  BY 1,2')  
AS ct ("start" int, "finish" int);
```

But, its output is not correct as expected. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this type of query is easy enough to do with conditional aggregation:

```
select start1,
       sum(case when finish1 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as finish1,
       sum(case when finish1 = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as finish2,
       sum(case when finish1 = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as finish3
from test
group by start1
order by start1;
```

Comment: That's correct but, I am working with big data and I have 180 000 000 start and end points. Is there any possible solution that could work for all the data at once?

Comment: I mean that I have numbers from 1 to some millions is not from 1 to 3.

Comment: Sorry, again, but I try it again adding a row it doesn't give me the proper answer. To clarify a bit more I am looking a way to do it like is written in the example 1 in the following page: http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/10/pivot-and-unpivot-in-sql-server/

but here is with pivot and I can't use pivot with postgresql (i think)